# Php PSR-7 response, get file mime-type

Tags: php, http, http-headers, mime-types, psr-7

I've got a `$response` variable, which implements `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`.

It contains info about downloaded file. How can I get mime-type of this file?

Comment: You could try `$response->getHeader('content-type')`. See https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/MessageInterface.php#L94

Comment: @Phil, for me `$response->getHeader('Content-Type')[0]` works perfectly. You may answer and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ResponseInterface` extends `MessageInterface`, you can use the [`getHeader($name)`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/MessageInterface.php#L94) or [`getHeaderLine($name)`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/MessageInterface.php#L115) method to retrieve the value of the `Content-Type` response header. For example...

```
$mimeType = $response->getHeaderLine('Content-Type');
```

Note: I used `getHeaderLine` as it's unlikely the `Content-Type` header will contain more than one value and this will save you treating the return value as a single-item array.

Comment: You say unlikely, while I consistently get content types such as `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. The `getHeader()` method in the Guzzle implementation does not split that up into two parts, as I would expect. Should PSR-7 be able to handle that extra "charset" part, or is that up to the application to do?

Comment: @Jason that's still only one header. The thing with HTTP headers is that they may be repeated with different values so robust implementations will always offer a collection of values per header name